# What is SpaceX's parachute problem that NASA is concerned about in the NASA ASAP report?

Tags: spacex, nasa, dragon-v2, parachute

The Washington Post's [NASA to launch safety review of SpaceX and Boeing after video of Elon Musk smoking pot rankled agency leaders](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/2018/11/20/nasa-launch-safety-review-spacex-boeing-after-video-elon-musk-smoking-pot-rankled-agency-leaders/) says:

> Earlier this year, Boeing had a propellant leak during a test of its emergency abort system. A safety advisory panel also found recently that Boeing still has a number of key tests that it has not completed, included tests of its spacecraft’s heat shield and parachute systems.
>
> It also found that SpaceX is struggling with “difficulties and problems” with the spacecraft’s parachute system. “Clearly crew cannot be risked without complete confidence in the parachute design,” the [panel found](https://oiir.hq.nasa.gov/asap/documents/ASAP_Fourth_Quarterly_2018_Public_Meeting_Minutes_TAGGED.pdf).

The linked report [NASA Aerospace Safety Advisory Panel, Public Meeting, Opening Remarks, October 11, 2018](https://oiir.hq.nasa.gov/asap/documents/ASAP_Fourth_Quarterly_2018_Public_Meeting_Minutes_TAGGED.pdf) says, (immediately after discussing COPV failures):

> In addition to this issue, recent parachute testing, both during the CCP qualification (qual) testing regimen and with some anomalies witnessed in the resupply contract (also handled by SpaceX), show difficulties and problems with parachute designs. Clearly, crew cannot be risked without complete confidence in the parachute design. It is an integral part of capsule return for both providers and a crucial element of crew safety.

What are the parachute problems of concern here? If I understand correctly non-crew Dragon capsules have been parachuting back to Earth at least several times. Is the Crewed Dragon capsule parachute system different in some way? Is there a specific test that hasn't been met satisfactorily?

Comment: meta: [Two SpaceX Dragon tags, is clarification needed?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1103/12102)

Comment: (Makes Jedi hand gesture) "There are no problems with the Dragon...**There are no problems with the Dragon**..."